# change the contrast and brightness of image using slider

Tags: ios, swift4.2, contrast

I am trying to change the contrast and brightness of an image using the slider, and I have created a slider programatically. When I am trying to vary the contrast by the slider, am getting an error like

> reason: '-[UISlider floatValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x103c4ffa0'`func viewforslide(){
>           vieew.frame = CGRect.init(x: 10, y:view.frame.size.height - 180, width: self.view.frame.size.width - 20, height: 40)
>           vieew.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
>           vieew.layer.cornerRadius = vieew.frame.size.height/2
>           view.addSubview(vieew)
>           createslider()
>       }

```
func createslider(){
    var sliderDemo = UISlider(frame:CGRect(x: 15, y: 5, width: vieew.frame.size.width - 30, height: 30))
    sliderDemo.minimumValue = 0.0
    sliderDemo.maximumValue = 1000.0
    sliderDemo.isContinuous = true
    sliderDemo.tintColor = UIColor.black
    sliderDemo.value = 500.0
    sliderDemo.addTarget(self, action:  #selector(_sldComponentChangedValue),for: .valueChanged)
    vieew.addSubview(sliderDemo)
}


@IBAction func _sldComponentChangedValue(sender: UISlider) {
  //  Set value to the nearest int
    sender.setValue(Float(roundf(sender.value)), animated: false)
    let newvalforslider = sender
    print("\(newvalforslider)")

    let displayinPercentage: Int = Int((sender.value/200) * 10000)
  //  contrastValueLabel.text = ("\(displayinPercentage)")
    self.imageView.image = results.enhancedImage
    let beginImage = CIImage(image: self.imageView.image!)
    let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIColorControls")
    filter?.setValue(beginImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
    filter?.setValue(sender.value, forKey: kCIInputContrastKey)
    var filteredImage = filter?.outputImage
    var context = CIContext(options: nil)
    imageView.image = UIImage(cgImage: context.createCGImage(filteredImage!, from: (filteredImage?.extent)!)!)
    var sliderValue = sender.value

}
```

`

If anyone helps me to do this, would be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is function `viewforslide` ?

Comment: What are you trying to do? in slider method you should get the slider value instead you're setting the value to the slider. Also at `sliderDemo.addTarget(self, action:  #selector(_sldComponentChangedValue),for: .valueChanged)` line `_sldComponentChangedValue` should be like `_sldComponentChangedValue(_ :)` so that it can pass the value to method parameter (sender).

Comment: viewer slide is a UIView  to which I have added this slider

Comment: I have resolved that ..but now am not able to apply the contrast properly that is the one I want to do..

Comment: the requirement is ..once I release the slider then that contrast should apply to the image otherwise it should show the original image

Answer (score 0):

While adding target method to `sliderDemo` you have given selector (`_sldComponentChangedValue`), which is not right, your actual method does receives an argument. That's the difference in methods name, so on slide you gets crash saying "***unrecognized selector sent to instance***"

instead do as follows

```
sliderDemo.addTarget(self, action: #selector(_sldComponentChangedValue(sender:)), for: .valueChanged);
```

Comment: I have resolved this issue. ..but now am not able to apply the contrast properly that is the one I want to do.. the requirement is ..once I release the slider then that contrast should apply to the image otherwise it should show the original image

Comment: @anisha  for that do set `sliderDemo.isContinuous = false` instead of `true`

Answer (score 0):

@anisha If you complicate previous Ans. try this new code.

```
func increaseContrast(_ image: UIImage) -> UIImage {
    let inputImage = CIImage(image: image)!
    let parameters =
    [
       "inputContrast": NSNumber(value: 2) // set how many contrast you want  
    ]
    let outputImage = inputImage.applyingFilter("CIColorControls", 
         parameters: parameters)
    let context = CIContext(options: nil)
    let img = context.createCGImage(outputImage, from: outputImage.extent)!
    return UIImage(cgImage: img)
}
```